Redirect from Salesforce to Visualforce Page in Community without logging in
My team is currently working to move a Visualforce page to a Digital Experience as for technical security reasons, we need this to run under our white-labeled domain.
We're having a tough time though figuring out a way to redirect to the page without a login screen popping up first.
Here's what we've tried so far:

Using NavigateEverywhere, we can redirect to the Experience using the URL. This works, but requires logging in to view the Experience before going to the page. We can view it successfully after logging in though.
We've tried using NavigationMixin's comm_standardpage, but it just shows a URL does not exist error. I get the feeling that this only works in the Portal, as I tried navigating to a non-Visualforce page and it didn't work.


I assume you've already set up all the permissions for guest user access to the Experience site  + the VF page + the object(s)?

Yep, it's setup to allow Guest Access. It's a Custom VF Page, so at the very least Object Access isn't required to access the page.

Turns out I just didn't have good search skills last week.
There's literally a help page showing how to do this:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_navigate.htm&type=5
